# Responsive grid of squares fitting window height

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to create responsive grid of squares (3x3 and then 5x5). The code below correctly creates a grid of squares that get smaller as the window shrinks. However, I would like to limit the maximum height of the entire container to the height of the browser window. Which means I have to limit the height of a single square. But when I set `min-height` and `max-height` to square, the width is not changing.

```css
.square-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(3,1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.square {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  aspect-ratio:1/1;
}
```

```html
<div class="square-container">
  <div class="square">1</div>
  <div class="square">2</div>
  <div class="square">3</div>
  <div class="square">4</div>
  <div class="square">5</div>
  <div class="square">6</div>
  <div class="square">7</div>
  <div class="square">8</div>
  <div class="square">9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the logic to the container

```css
.square-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr; /* equal rows*/
  gap: 10px;
  aspect-ratio: 1; /* make the container a square */
  /* limit the width and height */
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  /* center horizontally */
  margin: auto;
}

.square {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;=
  /* full width and height*/
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /**/
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="square-container">
  <div class="square">1</div>
  <div class="square">2</div>
  <div class="square">3</div>
  <div class="square">4</div>
  <div class="square">5</div>
  <div class="square">6</div>
  <div class="square">7</div>
  <div class="square">8</div>
  <div class="square">9</div>
</div>
```